# NetBeans will not download from remote location, but testing FTP is giving me success

Tags: java, netbeans, ftp

When i try to create a new project on my laptop with NetBeans 8.0 i get different errors when trying to download all files. It ranges from

"Cannot log out from Server (IP)
Reason: 215 UNIX Type: L8"

"Cannot list files for /" 
Reason: 215 UNIX Type: L8"

If i enable passive mode in the FTP settings i get

"Cannot log out from Server (IP)
Reason: Connection reset by peer: Socket write error"

"Cannot list files for /" 
Reason: Connection reset"

The wierd part is that when i go the FTP settings and press the Test Connection button i get a success message. I have the exact same project loaded in my other PC where it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a faulty installation . After i reinstalled it, it now works.

Comment: I got the same problem! What version of Netbean (8.1 or 8.0.2) and JDK (7 or 8) in your PC? I try to install new one (version 8.0.1, current is 8.1) in JDK 7. But, still get this problem!