# Netbean FTP Remote Host Error: "Cannot list files for / Reason: Connection reset" when Download/Upload

Tags: netbeans, ftp

After I've setup "Run Configuration" with "Remote Website (FTP, SFTP)", of course, connection testing is successfull. But I got this error:

> "Cannot list files for / Reason: Connection reset"

on download/upload/synchronize.. in my project.
There was [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959205/netbeans-will-not-download-from-remote-location-but-testing-ftp-is-giving-me-su), but the answer does not work in my situation.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the same problem
I am using windows 7

click `start` type `cmd` right click and click `Run as administrator`

copy this command

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”FTP Service” action=allow service=ftpsvc protocol=TCP dir=in
```

press enter

now copy second command

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
```

hit enter, and try uploading

Comment: this did not work for me. got error `A specified value is not valid.`

Comment: Try different quotation marks: netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="FTP Service" action=allow service=ftpsvc protocol=TCP dir=in

Comment: Note that you MUST run cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is "Firewall". Care about it, if anyone get the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

If like this problem and using Windows, need closing firewall protection.

1. From  Control Panel > System And Security > Windows Firewall,
2. Select Windows Firewall make active or passive from left menu.
3. Select Passive Windows Firewall and Save.